# C# Windows Form Показать данные в DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть List обьектов. Как показать их в DataGrid, изменить и вернуть обратно в List? (ItemsSource в MVVM WPF делает ето все)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компонент [DataGrid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.7.2) позволяет отображать и редактировать список ([List](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Для того, чтобы привязать список к DataGrid, используют метод [SetDataBinding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid.setdatabinding?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
dataGrid.SetDataBinding(GetListOfObjects(), "");
```

Так как редактировать в DataGrid можно только ссылочные типы (структуры передаются "по значению", поэтому для записи изменений будет создана копия, которая уничтожается сразу после записи), то ничего специально не нужно делать чтобы вернуть обратно список измененных объектов. Надо просто сохранить ссылку на список, который передали в SetDataBinding, и все измененные объекты будут там.

```
var listOfObjects = GetListOfObjects();
dataGrid.SetDataBinding(listOfObjects, "");
```

---

**Интересно почитать**
[Differences Between the Windows Forms DataGridView and DataGrid Controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/differences-between-the-windows-forms-datagridview-and-datagrid-controls)

Comment: а почему предлагаете использовать DataGrid, а не DataGridView?

Comment: @4per, потому что по замыслу в начале должен был идти ответ на поставленный вопрос, а после обоснованный совет использовать DataGridView. К сожалению, мне не удалось своими словами сформулировать достаточно убедительного обоснования, поэтому я ограничился ссылкой на MSDN.